# Can we do Property Binding on property of user-defined types using dot operator in Angular?

Tags: angular

This is something I am wondering if can be done in Angular.

I have a component A with an Input() attribute as user-defined type

```
export class A{

@Input() emp:Employee = new emp:Employee();

}
```

Another component B is trying to render A component. Here I don't want to pass all properties of Employee model to component A.

I know it can be done by creating an instance and assigning values to only relevant properties and then passing the instance to component A.

But what I am actually looking for something like this.

```
<app-a [emp.name]="'Jon'"></app-a>
```

I have seen such syntax while applying css like `[style.top.px]`

Is this possible for us to do with user-defined types?

If yes, can you guide me to some references?

Thanks.

Comment: you can't actually do this! you have to set the entire object as such

Comment: No, but you can just send the relavant information `[emp]="{name: 'Jon'}"`

Comment: @ritaj Thanks, this is also useful. Though I would hope that Authors bring something like this in next releases.